# Can you get a Philippines visa extended before having your passport stamped?

Tags: visas, passports, passport-stamps, philippines, visa-renewals

In [this article](https://liveinthephilippines.com/content/visa-run/), the writer says your 30-day visa can be extended at the immigration office before you have your passport stamped.

I've never been to an airport. How is it possible to have your visa extended before having your passport stamped, which I assume happens when you enter the country with no choice but to have your passport stamped?

Can you still extend your visa if your passport gets stamped? And what if you already have a visa? Do you have to take the entry visa too?

Sorry if my questions are all over the place.

Answer (score 1):

Specific to The Philippines, and the referenced article, you will find Immigration offices right in the arrivals terminal(s). The visa is not activated or effective until you arrive and present yourself for entry into the country, through an international arrivals hall or section of the airport. In some countries, eligible nationals can receive a visa on arrival, a process that takes place prior to, or during, presenting credentials (passport, visa) and seeking permission to enter.

Some countries allow current visa holders to request permission to extend their stay, usually by visiting the offices of the appropriate authorities (e.g., immigration, foreigners). You would need your passport, the current (unexpired) visa, pictures, fee, and any other documentation required (e.g., application form, accommodation verification, copies of passport pages, etc.)